# Spark Scala - Error Using rlike for Converting DataFrame Column to Time Type

Tags: regex, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, time

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to convert raw time strings (hh:mm:ss) stored in a Spark DataFrame, where I use a StructType with a column type of "string". The goal is to write these time values into a relational database where the target column type is "Time".

```
val timeRegex = "(([0-1]?[0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"
        var convertedData = newData

    newData.schema.fields.foreach { field =>
      val columnName = field.name
      val dataType = field.dataType

      if (dataType == StringType) {
        convertedData = convertedData.withColumn(
          columnName,
          when(expr(s"col($columnName) rlike '$timeRegex'"),
            to_utc_timestamp(substring(col(columnName), 1, 8), "HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp").cast("time"))
            .otherwise(col(columnName))
        )
      }
    }
```

newData is the dataframe containing my data and the time columns are string with hh:mm:ss format.
However, the issue arises when any string (even non-time strings like "ABCDF_12345") matches the timeRegex. This causes the otherwise block to attempt casting to a timestamp, resulting in an error.

I am seeking advice on how to modify the code or improve the regex to ensure that only valid time strings are converted, and others are left unchanged. The current regex seems to be too permissive, allowing non-time strings to match.

Any insights or alternative approaches to achieve this conversion in Spark SQL would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: String "ABCDF_12345" does not match regex. Big issue is: one column can have both Timestamp and String types, depending on condition, how is this possible?

Comment: I create a dataframe where column are StringType or TimestampType. My problem is that I have column with values like "11:12:33" that are "time" type in Postgres, but I don't have time type in Spark. i need something that converts me that kind of string in a type that can be inserted in time column in Postgres. How can I do?

Comment: One column cannot have two types at once.

Comment: I want to cast that column to a format compatible with "time" in Postgres, I don't want two types, but only one

Answer (score 0):

If Postgres Time column can accept Spark Timestamp, String fields with time can be casted to Timestamp; non-valid times will be casted as nulls:

```
val df = Seq("ABCDF_12345", "13:04:22").toDF
val timeRegex = "(([0-1]?[0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"

val stringFieldNames = df.schema.fields
  .filter(_.dataType == StringType)
  .map(_.name)

def castToTimestamp = (fieldName: String) => when(expr(s"$fieldName rlike '$timeRegex'"), col(fieldName).cast(TimestampType))
val result = stringFieldNames.foldLeft(df)((acc, fieldName) => acc.withColumn(fieldName, castToTimestamp(fieldName)))
```

Result:

```
+-------------------+
|value              |
+-------------------+
|null               |
|2023-12-04 13:04:22|
+-------------------+
```

Result schema:

```
root
 |-- value: timestamp (nullable = true)
```